# Фиксированное положение элемента на форме

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, которая представляет собой карту мира, в левом нижнем углу есть groupbox с информацией о странах. Есть функция масштабирования, при которой появляются полосы прокрутки. Проблема в том, что при прокрутке перемещается и сам groupbox. Получается, что если прокрутить изображение вниз, то groupbox уедет наверх. Как можно его закрепить, чтобы он всегда оставался в одном положении?

GroupBox создаю в конструкторе, не динамически. И полосы прокрутки появляются благодаря свойству AutoScroll элемента Panel. Сам gropubox расположен на picturebox, который в свою очередь расположен на panel.

Часть, где происходит масштабирование:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   // public static Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("img\\BigMap.png");
    public static Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("img\\BigMap.png");
    public static Bitmap myBitmapScale1 = new Bitmap("img\\BigMap.png");
    public static Bitmap myBitmapScale2 = new Bitmap("img\\BigMapScale2.png");

    public Graphics pctMap;
    public bool CheckClick = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AutoSize = true;
        //pctMap = this.pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        pictureBox1.Size = ClientSize;
        //pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        panel2.AutoScroll = true;

        pictureBox1.MouseWheel += pictureBox1_MouseWheel;        
    }
    //Масштабирование
    double scale = 1.0;
    
    private void pictureBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0) //scroll
        {
            if (scale < 2)
            {
                scale += 1;
                if (scale == 2)
                {
                    myBitmap = myBitmapScale2;
                    pictureBox1.Width = myBitmap.Width;
                    pictureBox1.Height = myBitmap.Height;
                    pictureBox1.Refresh();
                }
            }               
        }
        else if (e.Delta < 0)//unscroll
        {
            if (scale > 1)
            {
                scale -= 1;
                if (scale == 1)
                {
                    myBitmap = myBitmapScale1;
                    pictureBox1.Size = ClientSize;
                   
                    panel2.Width = 1920;
                    panel2.Height = 1022;

                    pictureBox1.Refresh();
                }
            }                  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Судя по описанному, родителем groupbox является picturebox. А нужно родителем сделать форму: `groupBox.Parent = this;`

Comment: Alexander Petrov, тогда **groupbox** перемещается на задний план, его перекрывает **panel** и его становится не видно.

Comment: `groupBox.BringToFront();`

Comment: Да, это работает, спасибо

Comment: Это можно сделать и в дизайнере формы, но описывать, как это сделать, намного сложнее. Проще в коде. В этом главная проблема дизайнеров.